# Jinja converting quotation marks to &#39

Tags: javascript, flask, jinja2

I'm using a flask project and at one point I render a template with the variable:

```
open_modal = "jQuery(document).ready(function($) {$UIkit.modal("#modal1").show();});
```

Which is then rendered in the template with the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    {{ open_modal }}
</script>
```

However, when I run the page and check the html it shows instead

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {$UIkit.modal(&#34;#modal1&#34;).show();});
```

And so I take it that the quotation mark (') is being converted into '&#34' which is messing with the Javascript syntax. How can this conversion be prevented?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default `jinja2` engine does the conversion. Update your code as below to use `safe` filter -

```
{{ open_modal | safe }}
```